# Must declare scalar variable in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which retrieves multiple rows of 3 column items. I am retrieving in the format of DataTable. When I debug it it gives me error

> Must Declare Scalar variable @Ticket.

But I have already declared that.

Stored procedure :

```
BEGIN

Declare @Ticket Numeric(28,0)
Declare @SQL VarChar(Max)
Declare @SQLUpdate VarChar(Max)

 Set @SQL='Select @Ticket=Ticket,VendorTicket[Vendor Ticket],Comments From dbo.VendorTickets Where NotifyOn <= GetDate() And IsNull(NotifyOn,0)<>0 '
 Exec(@SQL)

 Set @SQLUpdate='Update dbo.VendorTicket Set NotifyOn=0 Where Ticket=@Ticket'
 Exec(@SQLUpdate)

END
```

Code which calls stored procedure

```
SqlConnection oConn = null;
DataTable dtReturn = null;
try
{
getConnection(ref oConn, 1);
using (SqlStoredProcedure sspObj = new SqlStoredProcedure("dbo.usp_checkNotification", oConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
dtReturn = sspObj.ExecuteDataTable();
sspObj.Dispose();
}
closeConnection(ref oConn);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL for this? What is the datatype of `NotifyOn`?

Comment: NotifyOn Data type is DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using dynamic SQL?

Just do this

```
 Update dbo.VendorTickets
 Set NotifyOn=0 
 Where NotifyOn <= GetDate() 
 And NotifyOn IS NOT NULL
```

Note that setting a datetime (NotifyOn) to 0 will set it to 1900-01-01.

Comment: No Only One Table i have "VendorTickets"...Sorry its a mistake

Comment: i Have only one table first query do the select operation and second one do the update based on value return in first select query

Comment: In your example the first query I think you're trying to set values and return data. You can't do both

Comment: how can i check if Notify on is Greater than 1900-01-01 ?

Comment: WHERE NotifyON>'1900-01-01'.  Why not leave it null if an empty date is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select @Ticket=Ticket,VendorTicket[Vendor Ticket],Comments From dbo.VendorTickets Where NotifyOn <= GetDate() And IsNull(NotifyOn,0)<>0
```

means that resul of your select will be write to variable @Ticket, so @Ticket must be a table variable, but you declare @Ticket Numeric(28,0).
You can do what you want through next sql script:

```
Update dbo.VendorTicket 
Set NotifyOn=0 
Where Ticket in (
      Select Ticket 
      from dbo.VendorTickets 
      Where NotifyOn <= GetDate() And IsNull(NotifyOn,0)<>0
      )
```